# How can i solve the error when running xampp saying that the port/s are in use by another program?

Tags: xampp

I have xampp v 3.2.1 and i'm getting this error in red:

You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
Problem detected!
Port 21 in use by "C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k ftpsvc"!
FileZilla WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure FileZilla and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the FTP Server that is already running (most likely running via Windows Add/Remove Programs -> Windows Features).  Otherwise, you will need to change the port in the FileZilla settings located at %APPDATA%/FileZilla